# Amazon s3 stops working after a few hours ( Rails app )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, fog

I have rails app. I am using the gems carrierwave / minimagick / fog to manage and upload my images to Amazon S3. Some time everything is working well. But after a few hours I have this:

```
Excon::Error::Forbidden in Admin::ArticlesController#create



   Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden) excon.error.response :body => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code><Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAJ3GP4YRT36WGG6HQ</AWSAccessKeyId><RequestId>A53700AC2E670A28</RequestId><HostId>ha46+HNLMC47MirxR0sx3AoDbtvH/qdz5r7PgCDzagCGssuDA/D8+JhES3NRF1+greBf7Y1RpXo=</HostId></Error>" :cookies => [ ] :headers => { "Connection" => "close" "Content-Type" => "application/xml" "Date" => "Wed, 07 Sep 2016 08:22:08 GMT" "Server" => "AmazonS3" "x-amz-id-2" => "ha46+HNLMC47MirxR0sx3AoDbtvH/qdz5r7PgCDzagCGssuDA/D8+JhES3NRF1+greBf7Y1RpXo=" "x-amz-request-id" => "A53700AC2E670A28" } :host => "premierleag.s3.amazonaws.com" :local_address => "172.17.8.156" :local_port => 36578 :path => "/uploads/article/picture/44/DSC07321.JPG" :port => 443 :reason_phrase => "Forbidden" :remote_ip => "54.231.114.11" :status => 403 :status_line => "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n"
```

After this error, I create new access key and everything working fine, but after a few hours, I again have this error. What is wrong. Also, I attached the policy to a user, giving administrator access. Any thoughts? If I didn't give enough information, just tell me I'll add.

Comment: I wouldn't generally expect this to be an error. Is there any chance that the new policy/grant has an expiration attached?

Comment: I accidentally push to Github my credentials, then I delete them and change. Now everything working fine. I am not sure but maybe some Amazon protection worked. Really weird.

Comment: Yeah, could be. I think they might scan public repos or something.